# expected a parameter in the header

Tags: c++

I am trying to read and display the contents of a file named myDocument.txt, but I always get the following error with my header file.

> ./ReadDocument.h:22:24: error: expected parameter declarator          std::ifstream myflux("myDocument.txt");

What's going on?

Here is my ReadDocument.h:

```
class ReadDocument{
public:
    ReadDocument(); //empty constructor
    ReadDocument(const std::string& fileName); //constructor

    void documentContent();

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d);

    std::list<std::string> myList;
    std::ifstream myflux("myDocument.txt");

    if(myflux){
            //Getting the words from the file string by string
            std::string data; 
            while(myflux>>data){
                myList.push_back(data);
            }

            myflux.close();
    }
    else{
        std::string message = "\t\tERROR ==> This file doesn't exist.";
        throw FileDoesntExistException(message);
    }
```

};

Here is my ReadDocument.cpp:

```
#include "ReadDocument.h"

ReadDocument::ReadDocument(){}

void ReadDocument::documentContent(){}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d){

    for(std::list <std::string> :: const_iterator it = ReadDocument::myList.begin(); it!=ReadDocument::myList.end(); it++)
    std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

And this is my UseReadDocument.cpp

```
#include "ReadDocument.h"

int main(){
    ReadDocument rd("test.txt");
    std::cout<<rd<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried renamed the file and still the same problem.
I put it in the class, and doesn't change anything.
I always have the same error coming out.
and yes it is my entire code

Comment: Try to fix your formatting please.

Comment: You open myFlux, but close myFlux1

Comment: Is that your entire `ReadDocument.h`?  You're showing code that isn't within a class or function which will cause this error.

Comment: You are trying to write code (statements) right in the middle of class definition. What are you trying to achieve by this? There's no such thing in C++. Code has to reside inside functions. You can't just write statements in some random place.

Answer (score 1):

The part of your class after `myflux` is not in a method.
Did you want to put the code in the function `documentContent`, like this?

---

ReadDocument.h:

```
class ReadDocument{
public:
    ReadDocument(); //empty constructor
    ReadDocument(const std::string& fileName); //constructor

    void documentContent();

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d);

    std::list<std::string> myList;
    std::ifstream myflux("myDocument.txt");
};
```

---

ReadDocument.cpp:

```
#include "ReadDocument.h"

ReadDocument::ReadDocument(){}

void ReadDocument::documentContent(){
    if(myflux){
        //Getting the words from the file string by string
        std::string data; 
        while(myflux>>data){
            myList.push_back(data);
        }

        myflux.close();
    }
    else{
        std::string message = "\t\tERROR ==> This file doesn't exist.";
        throw FileDoesntExistException(message);
    }
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d){
    for(std::list <std::string> :: const_iterator it = ReadDocument::myList.begin(); it!=ReadDocument::myList.end(); it++)
    std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

By the way, you should avoid creating an empty constructor and filling it with nothing.
Since C++11 you should write `ReadDocument() = default;` in your header and remove  `ReadDocument::ReadDocument(){}` from the cpp.

Answer (score 1):

With your `class` your are `declaring` two `public` `variables` and trying to give each `instance` of your class these `default` `characteristics`. The solution in to put the default conditions in the `default` `constructor` as follows:

```
class ReadDocument{
private:
    std::list<std::string> myList; //moved member variables to private 
    std::ifstream myflux;          //part of class
public:
    ReadDocument(); //empty constructor
    ReadDocument(const std::string& fileName); //constructor

    void documentContent();

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d);
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "ReadDocument.h"
ReadDocument::ReadDocument()
{
    myflux.open("myDocument.txt");
    if(myflux){
            //Getting the words from the file string by string
            std::string data; 
            while(myflux>>data){
                myList.push_back(data);
            }

            myflux.close();
    }
    else{
        std::string message = "\t\tERROR ==> This file doesn't exist.";
        throw FileDoesntExistException(message);
    }
}

void ReadDocument::documentContent(){}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ReadDocument& d){

    for(std::list <std::string> :: const_iterator it =        
    d.myList.begin(); it!=d.myList.end(); it++)
        std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

Code will now associate `myflux` with `"myDocument.txt"` and `extract` the `file data` into `myList` by default (unless instantiated with string parameter for use with const string& constructor) for each `instance` of the `ReadDocument` `class`. As well as a few other fixes in the ostream function.

P.S* Assuming this is your entire `.cpp` file associated with the `ReadDocument` `class`, you forgot to implement the `constructor` containing the `const` `string&` `parameter`, `ReadDocument(const std::string& fileName)`.

Comment: In modern C++ it is perfectly legal to specify initializers for non-static members in class definition (as long as one uses proper syntax, i.e. the uniform initializer syntax).

Comment: @AnT I was reading something along those lines, but I believe that more pertains to built in types, such as char, or int. However, ifstream is an istream object. I could very well be mistaken though of course.

Comment: No, you can write initializers for non-static members of any type. These initializers will basically be used to implicitly generate constructor initializer list entries for these members.

Comment: Do you think you can post a source? I'm having trouble finding where to quote exact c++ mathematically defined standards

Comment: Yuu can find the general overview here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members . As for the standard, it is kinda scattered across the document, but `[class.mem]` would be a good starting point.

Comment: @NickPavini Tank you ! your code seams to be working. IHowever, the Ostream operator still doesn't work and display an error about a  "non static data  member "

Comment: Change ostream to a friend function. Friend functions can access private data members. @Amine AIT BOUZIAD

Comment: Actually im sorry, remove scope resolution from myList in the ostream function. Change made above.

Comment: Before removing the scope resolution i get the error saying : "Non static data member".  After removing it, an other error shows up saying "Undeclared identifier myList "

Comment: I found it! Scope resolve wasnt the problem should work with or without it. The code was missing an = sign. Assigning it to myList.begin(). :) @Amine AIT BOUZIAD

Comment: I corrected it earlier. it s still the same problem

Comment: Good for sure now! Haha. We passed in the object as d and need to reference myList as follows d.myList

Comment: Of course. that does make sense . its all the purpose of the ostream declaration. thank you for the help